# LINQ; Select Groups of Lines from a Text File

Tags: c#, linq

Greeting Gurus, I have a text file with groups of text that I need to seperate into seperate string arrays. How do I group these using the line "start:" as the delimiter? (groups may contain differing line counts but the all begin with "start:". Is this a job that LINQ can accomplish? (Each line has seperate data, it does not look that way in the preview).

```
            List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\test.txt").ToList();
```

start: data 1

boy: data 2

great: data 3

start: data 7

boy: data 8

great: data 9

girl: data 10

Answer (score 3):

may be there is a linq solution but when you simply can handle this with for loops, I think there isn't any need to linq, for example I think bellow code done what you want:

```
        var groups = new List<List<string>>();

        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            if (line.StartsWith("Start:"))
            {
                groups.Add(new List<string>());
            }
            groups[groups.Count - 1].Add(line);
        }
```

I'd assumed first line of your file starts with `Start:` else you should skip first lines until reach the first `start:`.

Answer (score 0):

`File.ReadAllText(@"C:\test.txt").split("start:");`

Will read the file and split the file into an aray of string on the start: tag.

Comment: I don't think this hits the mark. From his description and sample data, it looks like he needs lines 1-3 as a group, and then lines 4-7, and onward through the file, with each group beginning with the `start:****` line and ending before the next such line.

Comment: may be there is `start:` in middle of a line and in this case your approach is not good

Comment: If the data is that simple I see no reason to assume the case where the delimiter is in the fields.  I always like the stupid simple solution until it is invalid.